# micro services authentication using SAML and Identity Provider

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, spring-saml, siteminder

We are working on the development of micro services for our domain.

We have a requirement to secure the micro services using SAML.

I read through the SAML docs and see that there would an Identity provider to which we have register our application (SP) and also we should connect to IdP for authentication. I understand that we need to establish a circle of trust or federation between them.

I tried using the Spring Security SAML extension and SSOCircle.com as IdP for authentication using the sample application provided. I was able to successfully authenticate accordingly.

My question is, in a micro services architecture, we have multiple services. Since it is not a monolithic we cannot just add one service as a SP to the IdP.

That means  every micro service I have say, employee, department,sales etc should also be added as a separate SP application in IdP.

I am not sure if that makes sense or actually possible to do so.

If anyone has worked on a similar architecture/development can you please provide your thoughts on the best way to approach the security of micro services from the point of authentication.

Thanks,
bstechie

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this:

1. As you said, configure each micro-service as SP and each SP talk to IdP for SAML authentication.

   - This is suitable, if each micro-service has different set of users, groups and roles than others.
   - There could be multiple SPs, which admin need to maintain.
2. Consolidate and configure all micro-services to single SP at your domain (may be use Reverse Proxy Web-Server or Access Manager) and that single SP talk to IdP for SAML authentication.

   - This is suitable, if all micro-service has same set of users, groups and roles.
   - There could be only single SP that admin need to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes all micro-services would have same set of users but may have different groups and roles. I too feel having a single SP should be the way forward. But, I am not sure how we can configure a single SP for all services related to a domain using IdP. I am using public IdP , ssocircle.com to add service metadata by uploading it , which gets generated at service startup. Can you let me know how I can group the services at a single domain and add it to the IdP.

Comment: Simple solution would be, use Reverse Proxy Web-Server (like Apache Reverse Proxy or Nginx). (1). Add all your micro-service endpoints in config or policy files of reverse proxy. (2). Integrate Reverse-Proxy (using SAML module) and your SAML-SP servers to talk. (3). Now all services are protected and will go thru SAML authentication at IdP.
 
Please refer Reverse Proxy Web-server (like Apache Reverse Proxy or Nginx) further on how to achieve above said approach.