# Spring SAML Identity Delegation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, saml, adfs, spring-saml

I have a website acting as an SP authenticating against ADFS using Spring SAML. The website/ADFS Security works well. Now within the website, a variety of backend services need to be accessed. The REST services in the backend run as a Spring Boot application also configured as an SP authenticating against the same IDP (ADFS). 
How can I achieve identity delegation from the Website to the backend services? I cannot find any resources on configuring Spring SAML to forward claims to the 2nd SP.
Thanks!

This is not a duplicate. I need to find out how ADFS identity delegation can be used, whereby the website forwards the claims to the rest service, instead of the rest service trying to authenticate the technical user of the website which has called the rest service (e.g. the tomcat service actually calls the rest service, but by using identity delegation one should be able to forward the logged-in user claims so that the rest service executes by assuming the website user as the caller)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [micro services authentication using SAML and Identity Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966557/micro-services-authentication-using-saml-and-identity-provider)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I need to find out how ADFS identity delegation can be used, whereby the website forwards the claims to the rest service, instead of the rest service trying to authenticate the technical user of the website which has called the rest service (e.g. the tomcat service actually calls the rest service, but by using identity delegation one should be able to forward the logged-in user claims so that the rest service executes by assuming the website user as the caller)

Comment: ok sorry, just read "delegation from website to backend services" and thought I read something like that before. That said if it is possible for your environment, you may want to have a look at keycloak, which can be connected to adfs-servers as identity federation provider and gives you an openid-connect access token which is nicely integrated in the spring universe. using its spring boot/security adapters, it's no problem to map the claims and thus, to propagate it to as many services you want. But, it's another "app", for sure, so not sure if it fits your needs.